# Sum values based on ctiteria in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following data table from which I would like to sum the values of the field 'pts' for each 'pid' as follows:
The sum of the top 3 values per 'cont' plus the values of any other 'cont' per 'pid'. The results should be presented in DESC order by 'total'

```
+--------+-----+------+
|  pid   | pts | cont |
+--------+-----+------+
| 121693 |  40 |    1 |
| 121693 |  80 |    2 |
| 121693 | 120 |    1 |
| 121693 | 100 |    1 |
| 121693 | 500 |    1 |
| 121694 |  20 |    1 |
| 121694 |   0 |    2 |
| 121694 |  30 |    3 |
| 121695 |   0 |    1 |
| 121695 |  30 |    2 |
| 121695 |   0 |    1 |
+--------+-----+------+
```

In this example the query should return something like this

```
+--------+-------+
|  pid   | total |
+--------+-------+
| 121693 |   800 |
| 121694 |    50 |
| 121695 |    30 |
+--------+-------+
```

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be `121693 |   840`

Comment: Nope. It's correct 121693 has 800 pts because it selects the Top 3 from cont = 1 plus 80 WHERE cont = 2

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT pid, SUM(Pts) AS Total
FROM your tablename
GROUP BY Pid
ORDER BY TOTAL

(Requires testing and minor fixes on small syntax)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't return the correct results as it doesn't take into account the top 3 values per cont.

Comment: Change SELECT DISTINCT to SELECT TOP 3   and order it by DESC

Comment: Again this is not correct because I don't want the Top 3 values per pid BUT the Top 3 per 'cont' per 'pid' + the rest values from the other 'cont'.

Comment: ok. I just saw your edited thread.  I used an aggregate function so surely SQL server already does that for you without having to show this in the query. each row of record is automatically aggregated accordingly. But yes, you can also extra lines of coding.

Comment: @Bakudan works fine and with TOP 3 it gives him the dataset he needs. the only issue we can all see from the dataset provided doesn't follow the correct figures to the right cont.  So whether this is a typo is beyond me.

Comment: @user7568042 - I know, there is 1 addtional row. The point was to add a demo. It is always nice if there is such a thing to add one, especially if it is a simple one.

Comment: @user7568042 The result dataset is correct. Please read carefully what the initial question asks. I need the SUM of the values per 'cont' but only the Top 3 values in case there is more than 3 values of the same cont. For example for  121693 should be 800 because 500+120+100 from cont = 1 plus 80 from cont = 2. Is it clear now? Sorry but your query doesn't return the correct result.